# How to create a new instance of a class with Ninject, inside of a dependency project? (not in the bootstrapped project)

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm working on a project that has multiple layers of architecture. These layers are in their own class library projects, but all in the same solution. At the lower layers, I've got the repository pattern going, with my models, repositories and dbcontext. On top of my repositories sits a service layer, which contains all of my business logic. Right now, my code for instantiating and using these various components looks like this, in my unit tests:

```
using (var context = m_kernel.Get<IPortalContext>())
{
    var accountRepository = m_kernel.Get<IAccountRepository>(new ConstructorArgument("context", context));
    var eventRepository = m_kernel.Get<IEventRepository>(new ConstructorArgument("context", context));

    var accounts = m_kernel.Get<IAccountService>(new ConstructorArgument("repository", accountRepository));
    var events = m_kernel.Get<IEventService>(new ConstructorArgument("repository", eventRepository));

    var account = accounts.GetByUsername("test@test.com");
}
```

You can see I create a context, then I create my repositories and give them the existing context, finally I create my services and give them the repository. Then, I am free to use the services.

That code is very verbose, though. I can make it cleaner by creating the repository instances inside of the services, instead of outside.

My confusion comes while trying to do this, though. I use Ninject for my DI, and I want to create an instance of the class bound to the `IAccountRepository` interface inside of my `IAccountService` constructor. On top of that, it needs to know to use the provided `IPortalContext` as well.

Do I have to add Ninject as dependency to my service layer project and create a new Kernel in there and use Kernel.Get() inside for the `IAccountService` constructor? Or is there a way to tell Ninject to do this all from my unit test, for example?

Comment: Creating the repositories inside of the services is not dependency injection. If you do it that way, you'll be using Ninject as a Service Locator, which is arguably an anti-pattern. The architecture you have here, with dependencies injected into the classes that need them, is the way IOC containers like Ninject are meant to be used. Ideally IOC containers should only be used in one place in your application, not spread out across classes and projects. For more info, check out the book "Dependency Injection in .Net" by stackoverflow user Mark Seemann, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create an instance of the class bound to the `IAccountRepository` interface inside of my `IAccountService` constructor

Then why are you using NInject?  That dependency should be *injected* (hence the name), not created within the service.

It may seem "cleaner" to do this inside the service, but you lose all of the benefit of loosely coupling your layers.

If you find you're repeating these 6 lines of code (which is not "verbose" IMHO) then you could refactor that into a separate function (in your unit tests and your app layer) and call it whenever you need to.

Comment: Alright then, perhaps I'll just stick to my current implementation.

Comment: I am not trying to kick up any dirt here, but trust me when I say you are not alone. I have been in the same situation as you and everyone loves to say "That's not how you use DI!" but provides no explanation on how to do what you are talking about. My conclusion is Service Locator is unavoidable no matter how many times people call it an anti-pattern. Comes down to need. DI is severely overrated.